# CKEditor exception whilst using the PasteFromWord plugin

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I've recently upgraded to the latest version of CKEditor 4, and have hit this exception which I can't seem to solve:

```
Unhandled exception at line 5, column 105 in file:///ScriptsLibrary/ckeditor/plugins/pastefromword/filter/default.js
0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'styles' of undefined or null reference
```

This exception arises from the following snippet of code, located in `default.js`, inside the [PasteFromWord plugin](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/examples/pastefromword.html):

```
(function(){function r(){return!1}var n=CKEDITOR.tools,B=CKEDITOR.plugins.pastetools,t=B.filters.common,k=t.styles ...
```

The actual exception is due to the styles object not existing:

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.pastetools.filters.common.styles
```

Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please add the exception and the link to the plugin you're using.

Comment: @Azeem - Sure, sorry for the lack of information! I've updated the question.

Comment: For future reference, you can go through [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section and [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: So, you're getting this exception on loading/initializing?

Comment: @Azeem - Thanks, I'll make sure my future posts match the expected format.

Comment: @Azeem - I'm getting this issue upon loading/initializing, but it's odd that it worked with the previous version.

Comment: Can you specify the version, please? Also, how did you integrate the plugin? Toolbar button or command configuration?

Comment: @Azeem - Sure, I'm using CKEditor 4.14, and it has been integrated via toolbar button.

Comment: Please make sure that you're using [the downloaded plugin](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/pastefromword). I just compared the code of the existing plugin and the downloaded one. They both differ. The existing one has only one `filter` folder and `default.js` in it. The other one has icons files, `plugin.js`, etc.

Comment: @Azeem - I just tried your suggestion, and it, unfortunately, didn't work. I'll keep looking into the issue, as it's probably some issue my end.

Comment: Actually, I was pointing out the difference between the code that you've posted in your question and the code that the downloaded plugin has. You need to verify if the downloaded code is in the `plugins` directory and if its configuration is properly done.

Comment: You might need to replace the existing `pastefromword` folder with the new one. Also, if you've done additional configuration then please update that as well. The information how you're currently loading CKEditor and its relevant configuration files would also be helpful along with your setup instructions. For example, `app.js`, `index.html`, `plugin.js`, etc.

Comment: @Azeem - Sure, so the config.js and all CKEditor's JavaScript files are all loaded via an HTML file, which in turn is used by an embedded IE11 browser. The related config file can be found on the ticket that I've raised on GitHub - https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor4/issues/4056